.htaccess virtual directory as a $_GET parameter
While working with multiple databases I have a database ID stored in $_SESSION and I would like to pass that ID within the url instead, as such:
Now: my.domain.app/hrm/employees
New: my.domain.app/Sa3fcXsaL/hrm/employees - where Sa3fcXsaL is the database ID (random string) and should always be passed to $_GET["database_id"] within the page.
I would like to create this effect as cloudflare uses:
https://dash.cloudflare.com/7d417df8e2ac/
https://dash.cloudflare.com/7d417df8e2ac/websites
https://dash.cloudflare.com/7d417df8e2ac/domains/example.com/contacts


You give exactly one example of a rewrite, which works. What else are you trying to rewrite to what, and what have you tried to do so, and where might you be stuck?

@deceze I think my question is 100% very clear. As said, if I were to do it manually for a specific page, it works. Working with multiple directories and sub-directories and pages, that wouldn't make sense. So is there a way to do this across the entire app with RewriteCond so that I wouldn't had to RewriteRule for every single page?

You certainly can implement a rule generally taking the first "folder" from the requested path and add it to the GET arguments. That means however that you have to guarantee that this structure will always exist, since you cannot tell that ID apart from other "folder" names on a protocol level. And it means your rewriting process will become more complex, since you have multiple rules implemented in different locations, rarely a wise decision. You just have to make sure that this general ID rewriting rule will get applied first , so implement it atop the first configuration file.

Well… is there a general pattern you can apply to all pages in a single rule? Or are your pages so disparate that you need a completely different pattern for each? If the latter, I'd first think about making your URLs less complex and more uniform. Maintaining a giant .htaccess file is a huge headache in the long run, and will only make things more and more complex.

@arkascha the idea is that this random "database_id" will always be the first "path" in the URL. So somehow if it can be omited and passed as $_GET["database_id"] every time

@deceze To me it seems that its a very standard procedure that many SaaS use that have multiple accounts, either as a subdomain or in their path as a "directory". Google Workspace, Stripe even Cloudflare

But they define one general pattern which works for all, e.g. app/(\w+)/(\w+)/(\w+) foo/$2/$3?bar=$1. They do not define individual rewrite rules for every single possible URL.

@deceze I would define one pattern at 99% most cases and then manually set 10 or 15 new paths manually under it, I wouldn't mind.

@deceze could you give me the answer if I were to use one general pattern which works for all?

@deceze
eg. Cloudflare goes https://dash.cloudflare.com/RANDOM_STR/domains/DOMAIN/contacts and its exactly what im looking for

@arkascha see my updated question

Whatever cloudflare does (I have no idea and you don't say), why don't you implement a rewrite rule according to what you ask?

Summarising the discussion in the comments: you should keep your rewrite rules as minimalist as possible. Maintaining a long .htaccess file with many possibly conflicting rules is a giant headache. What other services like CloudFlare or even Stack Overflow do is mostly not based on rewrite rules; they process URLs in whatever their backends are written in using routing, and/or use one pattern applied to all URLs as much as possible.

Having said that, yes, you can repeatedly modify your request in multiple steps by chaining several rules, e.g.:
RewriteRule ([^/.]+)/(.*) $2?database_id=$1
RewriteRule hrm/employees/? app/hrm/employees.php

Given a request to /Sa3fcXsaL/hrm/employees as example, the request is rewritten in two steps:

/Sa3fcXsaL/hrm/employees → /hrm/employees?database_id=Sa3fcXsaL
/hrm/employees?database_id=Sa3fcXsaL → /app/hrm/employees.php?database_id=Sa3fcXsaL


This instantly gives me a redirect to var/www?database_id=app

While this RewriteRule ^app/([^/.]+)/?$   app/$2?database_id=$1 [L] workes only for the homepage

Well, no, these rules do not redirect you to var/www because that's not mentioned anywhere in those rules. You likely have some interference with some other rules of yours. As I said… it gets complicated quickly. You can test your rules here for better visibility on what's happening: https://htaccess.madewithlove.com.
